# PlatformIO collect2.exe linker error with: undefined reference to

Tags: c++, linker, platformio

I am trying to modularize my code by crating git submodules for libraries/dependencies, but I am running into a linker problem `collect2.exe`. I am compiling and building using PlatformIO in VScode.

The linking error occurs with the following structure. Please note I have simplified the names and structure for illustration.

```
|--include
|--lib
|  |--MyLibFolder
|    |--src
|      |-myLib.h
|      |-myLib.cpp
|    |--ExternalLibFolder
|      |--src
|        |-externalLib.h
|        |-externalLib.cpp
|--src
|  |-main.cpp
```

Where:

```
//main.cpp
#include "myLib.h"
```

and

```
//myLib.h
#include "../ExternalLibFolder/src/externalLib.h"
void myTask(void * parameter);

//myLib.cpp
#include "myLib.h"
void myTask(void * parameter) {
  aClass myClass(someVal);
  myClass.init();

  while(1) {
    //blah
  }
}
```

and

```
//externalLib.h
class aClass :anInheritance{
  aClass(someType parameter);
  void inti();
}

//externalLib.cpp
aClass::aClass(someType parameter){}
void aClass::init() {
  anInheritance::begin();
}
```

This structure returns the following error:

```
In function `MyTask()`
myLib.cpp:(.text._....): undefined reference to `aClass::aClass(someType &)'
myLib.cpp:(.text._....): undefined reference to `aClass::init()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
***[.pio\build\teensy41\firmware.elf] Error 1
```

NOTE: when I place all source files into the `lib/MyLibFolder/src` folder then the program runs and compiles perfectly. Alternatively if I place every submodule under the lib/ folder then the program also runs fine. Its only once I split the code into submodules in a recursive manner that I get this problem.

I am not sure how to approach this linker issue and any help would be great

Comment: You show the ***declarations*** of the `aClass` functions, but where is the ***definition*** (their implementation)? Do you build with the source file where the definition (implementation) is?

Comment: You should be getting another error actually, because `aClass myClass(someType someVal);` declares a *function* named `myClass`, not an `aClass` object.

Comment: Please excuse, im only recently learning about linkers and compilers, but if I understand you correctly; aClass is defined in the function myMethod. May I ask you to elaborate on your second question please (build source file...?)

Comment: Not sure if the current error is masking another error, but that the above set of errors are the only ones at this stage.

Comment: Now, *how do you build* your project? How do you build the library? How do you build your program? How do you *link* with the library?

Comment: the honest truth, I dont know. PlatformIO deals with all that. The platform.ini file is also pretty much default.

Comment: @Misha Regardless of what tool you're using to build your application, you must know the basics of compiling and linking a multi-module C++ and what the compiler and linker are looking for.  This is where clicking a button and relying on some tool to build everything, without you knowing the basics of how a C++ built, is not beneficial.  Granted, the build tool makes it easy to put projects together, launch the compiler and linker, etc.  but you must know the basics of what source code is, what an object file is, and the job of the compiler and linker.

Comment: @Paul, I appreciate the feedback, and while this is on the list of areas that need upskilling, it does not help solve the problem right now. What steps or what questions need to be asked to resolve this?

Comment: I have done some research after your comment on compilers and linkers. (I have updated the problem task with some minor specifics) By the looks of it the issue I am having is a problem with the linker. I get a collec2.exe error. Any further pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the build to be successful the following two lines had to be added to the platformio.ini file:

```
lib_extra_dirs = lib/MyLibFolder/ExternalLibFolder
lib_ldf_mode = chain+
```

I found one really strange thing while debugging to which I dont have an answer to. I am running FreeRTOS and the truly strange thing is that the program built successfully when:

1. I remove `lib_ldf_mode = chain+` line from platformio.ini file
2. loop() looks like this:

```
void loop() {
  /*
  #include externalLib.h
  */
}
```

As soon as I remove the `/* #include externalLib.h */` line from loop() OR I change it to `//#include externalLib.h` the linker ran into the issue again. I then had to add the `lib_ldf_mode = chain+` line to platformio.ini.